# Change the default folder where temporary profile is created by firefox

Tags: firefox, watir, profile, headless

I am getting Errno::ENOSPC error while trying to run watir tests headlessly on firefox. Actually the cause of this error is that I am logged it from a non-root user and when I run my tests, it tries to create directory for temporary firefox profile in 'tmp' folder. Because it doesn't use 'sudo', it is giving this error.

If I do 'mkdir xyz' in 'tmp', it gives 'No space in device' error, which is same as above.

How can I change the default profile folder (which is '/tmp') where webdriver is trying to create temporary profile? I want webdriver to create the temporary profile by itself but in the folder which I can set.

I am using Linux, ruby 1.9.2p320, selenium-webdriver 2.26.0 and watir-webdriver 0.6.1.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to monkey patch selenium-webdriver, as there does not appear to be a built in way to specify the directory that includes the temporary profiles.

**Background**

Seleium-webdriver (and therefore watir-webdriver) creates the temporary Firefox profile `directory in \selenium-webdriver-2.26.0\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\profile.rb` using the method:

```
def layout_on_disk
    profile_dir = @model ? create_tmp_copy(@model) : Dir.mktmpdir("webdriver-profile")
    FileReaper << profile_dir

    install_extensions(profile_dir)
    delete_lock_files(profile_dir)
    delete_extensions_cache(profile_dir)
    update_user_prefs_in(profile_dir)

    profile_dir
end
```

The temporary folder is created by the:

```
Dir.mktmpdir("webdriver-profile")
```

Which is defined in the [tmpdir library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html). For the `Dir.mktmpdir` method, the second optional parameter defines the parent folder (ie where to create the temporary profile). If no value is specified, as in this case, the temporary folder is created in `Dir.tmpdir`, which in your situation is the 'tmp' folder.

**Solution**

To change where the temporary folder is created, you can monkey patch the `layout_on_disk` method to specify your desired directory in the call to `Dir.mktmpdir`. It would look like:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

module Selenium
module WebDriver
module Firefox
class Profile
    def layout_on_disk

        #In the below line, replace 'your/desired/path' with
        #  the location of where you want the temporary profiles
        profile_dir = @model ?
            create_tmp_copy(@model) : 
            Dir.mktmpdir("webdriver-profile", 'your/desired/path')

        FileReaper << profile_dir

        install_extensions(profile_dir)
        delete_lock_files(profile_dir)
        delete_extensions_cache(profile_dir)
        update_user_prefs_in(profile_dir)

        profile_dir
    end
end
end
end
end

browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
#=> The temporary directory will be created in 'your/desired/path'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the environment variable [TMPDIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMPDIR) is enough to make ruby, and selenium, write their temporary files where you want.

From http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html :

`Dir.tmpdir‘s return value might come from environment variables (e.g. $TMPDIR).`

So, if you're in your shell:

`export TMPDIR="/whatever/you/want/"`